# ActionFunction not rendering to create a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, actionfunction

Create a dynamic search custom using the ActionFunction for rendering the JS function to post the values to controller. The search is not working.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public class Applicantcontroller {
   private String soql {get;set;}
   public List<Applicant__c> Applicants {get; set;}
   public Applicantcontroller() {
    soql = 'Select Id,Name,Existing_Employee__c,ApplicantStreet__c,ApplicantCounty__c,ApplicantState__r.Name,ApplicantZip_Code__c from Applicant__c where Name!=null';
    runQuery();
  }
   // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {

    try {
     Applicants  = Database.query(soql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
    }
  }
  public PageReference runSearch() {
    String applicantName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantName');
    String applicantcounty = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantcounty');
    String applicantstate = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantstate');
    String applicantzipcode = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantzipcode');

  soql = 'Select Id,Name,Existing_Employee__c,ApplicantStreet__c,ApplicantCounty__c,ApplicantState__r.Name,ApplicantZip_Code__c from Applicant__c where Name!=null';
    if (!applicantName.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Name LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(applicantName)+'%\'';
    if (!applicantcounty.equals(''))
      soql += ' and ApplicantCounty__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(applicantcounty)+'%\'';  
    if (!applicantstate.equals(''))
      soql += ' and ApplicantState__r.Name LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(applicantstate)+'%\'';  
     if (!applicantzipcode.equals(''))
      soql += ' and ApplicantZip_Code__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(applicantzipcode)+'%\'';
    // run the query again
      runQuery();
      return null;
     }
   }
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Applicantcontroller" sidebar="false">
  <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>
  <apex:includescript value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchapplicant(
          document.getElementById("applicantName").value,
          document.getElementById("applicantcounty").value,
          document.getElementById("applicantstate").value,
          document.getElementById("applicantzipcode").value
          );
      }
   </Script>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:outputpanel > 
  <apex:actionFunction name="searchapplicant" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="example">
          <apex:param name="applicantName" value="" />
          <apex:param name="applicantcounty" value="" />
          <apex:param name="applicantstate" value="" />
          <apex:param name="applicantzipcode" value="" />
      </apex:actionFunction> 
    <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                     <h3 class = "panel-title">Applicant Search Filter Criteria</h3>
                </div>
           </div>          
            <form class="form-search">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                    <label for="inputdefault">Applicant Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicantName" type="text" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                    <label for="inputdefault"> County</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicantcounty" type="text" onkeyup="doSearch();" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                    <label for="inputdefault"> State</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicantstate" type="text" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                    <label for="inputdefault"> ZipCode</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicantzipcode" type="text" onkeyup="doSearch();" />
                </div>
                <div class="container" align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Contacts to Event</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
       </apex:outputPanel>
 <apex:outputpanel >
<table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"/></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Current Employee</th>
         <th> Street</th>
         <th> County</th>
         <th> State</th>
         <th>Zip Code</th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <apex:repeat value="{!Applicants}" var="applicant">
      <tr>
         <th></th>
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.Name}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!applicant.Exisitng_Employee__c}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.RDContactsStreet__c}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantCounty__c}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantState__r.Name}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantZip_Code__c}"/></td>
      </tr>
      </apex:repeat>
   </tbody>
</table>
</apex:outputpanel>
</apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your page have different controller name then was maintained above. Does it really compiled right by server? Pay attention on the page controller name on the <apex:page controller ="" attribute.

Comment: that's my bad actually I changed the controller name but still thats not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is that if a parameter isn't provided, it will be *null*, which will crash your if statements:

```
    if (!applicantName.equals('')) // System.NullPointerException can happen here.
```

Instead, use the safer String.isNotBlank:

```
    if(String.isNotBlank(applicantName)) // Safe from System.NullPointerException
```

Secondly, your query is initialized in two different places, which increases maintenance and increases the odds of an error. Instead, build the query in runQuery.

```
public void runQuery() {
    soql = 'Select Id,Name,Existing_Employee__c,ApplicantStreet__c,ApplicantCounty__c,ApplicantState__r.Name,ApplicantZip_Code__c from Applicant__c';
    String applicantName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantName');
    String applicantcounty = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantcounty');
    String applicantstate = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantstate');
    String applicantzipcode = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('applicantzipcode');
    String[] whereClause = new String[0];

    soql = 'Select Id,Name,Existing_Employee__c,ApplicantStreet__c,ApplicantCounty__c,ApplicantState__r.Name,ApplicantZip_Code__c from Applicant__c';
    if (String.isNotBlank(applicantName)) {
        whereClause.add('Name LIKE :applicantName');
        applicantName += '%';
    }
    if (String.isNotBlank(applicantCounty)) {
        whereClause.add('ApplicantCounty__c LIKE :applicantCounty');
        applicantCounty += '%';
    }
    if (String.isNotBlank(applicantstate)) {
        whereClause.add('ApplicantState__r.Name LIKE :applicantstate');
        applicantstate += '%';
    }
    if (String.isNotBlank(applicantzipcode)) {
        whereClause.add('ApplicantZip_Code__c LIKE :applicantzipcode');
        applicantzipcode += '%';
    }
    if(!whereClause.isEmpty()) {
        soql += ' WHERE '+String.join(whereClause,' AND ');
    }
    Applicants  = Database.query(soql);
}
```

---

Edit: I just noticed you're using a "table" element, and trying to re-render that element. You can't just reRender arbitrary elements, they must be *Visualforce* elements. You can fix this easily by wrapping your table in an "apex:outputText":

```
<apex:outputText id="example">
    <table class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"/></th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Current Employee</th>
             <th> Street</th>
             <th> County</th>
             <th> State</th>
             <th>Zip Code</th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <apex:repeat value="{!Applicants}" var="applicant">
          <tr>
             <th></th>
              <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.Name}"/></td>
              <td><apex:outputField value="{!applicant.Exisitng_Employee__c}"/></td>
              <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.RDContactsStreet__c}"/></td>
              <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantCounty__c}"/></td>
              <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantState__r.Name}"/></td>
              <td><apex:outputText value="{!applicant.ApplicantZip_Code__c}"/></td>
          </tr>
          </apex:repeat>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Made these changes to my controller but still the search is not working.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner You also had a minor problem with your Visualforce I just noticed. Updated this answer to reflect that problem.

Comment: I tried to use the apex:ouputtext but still its not rendering also my datatable style is missing since I moved the id="example".  How can i assign this class attribute to outputtext to keep datatble style

Comment: @SalesforceLearner You should change your CSS to use a class instead of an Id.